# Dropdown topmenu subcategory

Tags: magento-1.8, topmenu

I have a top menu of subcategories of **Default category**. Every subcategory has its own subcategories.

For example, i have now a top menu with **books, music, e-books, ...** and books have its own categories **romance, nonfiction, poetry,...** .

I would like when i hover **books** to have a dropdown with romance, nonfiction and so on.

Does magento have this feature ? if not, how can i accomplish this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a standard feature of Magento.

Make sure your root category (the one above books, music, e-books) is correctly assigned to your store (`System > Manage Stores`).

The categories need to be set to `active` and the option "Include in Navigation Menu" needs to be set to `Yes`. You can find this option on the category settings page.

Comment: I did all that, when i click on "Books" in top menu, i'm redirected to category view of books and i have a list of subcategories shown in the left. What i want is to have them dropped down instantly in responsive way. I don't know if i made myself clear.
Thank you for your help.